# How to capture a drag event in AngularJs ng-nestable plugin?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-nestable

I need a way to capture a "drag" event in the AngularJs ng-nestable plugin(based on JQuery nestable).

The documentation says absolutely nothing about events. When googling the issue, though, i found this discussion: [event in jquery nestable](https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable/pull/50)

I need to be able to capture these events with the AngularJs equivalent. Any ideas?

Comment: why not use an angular tree module?

Comment: Thank you charlieftl, i switched to that module, and it's a breeze :-)

Comment: probably a lesson you'll remember...look for angular resources first. glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to leverage the html5 drag and drop api, you can create a directive that hooks into the drag events.

```
     return {
        link: function (scope, elt, attrs) {
          var element = elt[0];
          element.ondragover = function() {

            console.log('drag event fired');

            scope.$evalAsync(function() {

              scope.model.message = "im being modified by the drag event";
            })


          }


          element.onclick = function() {

            scope.$evalAsync(function() {

              scope.model.message = "im being modified by the click event";
            })
          }
        }
```

Heres a working demonstration [plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/w2UFt5yGWtoiU6fuS3qg?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I already went ahead and used the angular tree module instead